# how to implement a video stream unto a webpage using a Raspberry Pi and being able to see the terminal without connecting HDMI cables

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2

i am quite conversant with Raspberry Pi and python language which i love very much that i was looking at videos on Youtube about Raspberry pi and i came cross this [video](https://youtu.be/9QbIDQHhmi8) which got me really intrigued on how he achieved the whole process about being able to still view the Raspberry pi terminal without actually connecting any HDMI cables to the monitor i will really appreciate it if anyone could tell me how this was done as i would love it for personal use and to enlarge my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

If you look at e.g. 4 min 27s on the video you will see he is using Remote Desktop Connection to an IP address.

You need to set up Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) on the Pi, then use an RDP client on the computer - not sure if he's using Windows or Mac. Other types of remote desktop software with other protocols are available. This guide discusses first VNC (on the Pi) and the RealVNC application (on the PC), and further down XRDP (on the Pi) and Windows Remote Desktop Connection (on the PC).

http://www.circuitbasics.com/access-raspberry-pi-desktop-remote-connection/

Comment: Thank you so much i really do appreciate it as you have cleared my doubt and added to my knowledge thank you once again.